# How to get user input variables to update in the spyder IDE variable explorer using tkinter library?

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter, spyder

How do I get the spyder IDE to update the variable explorer when getting an input from an entry field using the tkinter library?

I am new to programming GUI's using python's tkinter library. I am trying to make a simple GUI that gets the users input value from an entry field once a button is pressed. The problem I'm having is actually seeing this variable in spyders variable explorer. When I press the button the user_input variable prints to the console, but does not get updated in the variable explorer. When I close the GUI after pressing the button and stop the script it also does not update.

I am expecting a string variable called "user_input" to show up in the variable explorer after pressing the button or closing the GUI, but this does not appear to be happening.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_user_input():
    input_value = entry.get()
    print(input_value)

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry('300x200')
window.title('Get User Input')

entry = tk.Entry(window,width = 35)
entry.pack(pady=15)

button = tk.Button(window,width=30,text="Get User Input",command=get_user_input)
button.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

In the future I would like to utilize the tkinter library to grab a filepath from the user to open a csv file and convert the file to a dataframe using the pandas library. This is much more difficult to program if I can not see the updated dataframes in the variable explorer once the button is pressed. I am experiencing the same problem, where I can print the dataframe value to the console, but it does not update in the variable explorer.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def get_user_input():
    input_value = entry.get()
    print(input_value)
    df = pd.read_csv(input_value)
    df = df.iloc[:,1]
    print(df.head())

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry('300x200')
window.title('Get User Input')

entry = tk.Entry(window,width = 35)
entry.pack(pady=15)

button = tk.Button(window,width=30,text="Get User Input",command=get_user_input)
button.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```